# How do I download bootstrap static files into my rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I know I put the files into my vendor folder but where in that folder and what are the steps???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following gem:

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Use the following command to get static bootstrap files:

```
rails generate bootstrap:install static
```